# Custom fields not appearing in advanced search

Tags: custom-fields, civireport, advanced-search

I have a custom field set called "My Custom Info." In this set I had fields named "Group" and "Mentor" along with 4 other fields but, for a good reason, I deleted Group and Mentor and replaced these with Group1 and Mentor1.

Group1 and Mentor1 appear in the Custom Field Preview pane & when viewing the individual records (along with the other 4 fields) with a contact search.

BUT Group1 and Mentor1 DO NOT appear as a column option for a Constituent Summary report nor in Advanced Search (for instance, I cannot search within Group1). The other 4 fields DO appear.

In other words, I can run an advanced search with a custom view and the correct data for Group1 and Mentor1 appear for each record. But if I try to do an advanced search for just one of the Group1 values, My Custom Info omits both Group1 and Mentor1 but shows the other 4 options.

What have I done to My Custom Info that is causing this?

Using CiviCRM 5.59.3

Answer (score 1):

In the custom field config there's a box for "is searchable". It's unchecked by default to avoid hitting mysql limits and for performance.

Comment: DUH. Thanks that did it.